# git bundle create

Tags: git, git-bundle

I am using git version 1.7.10.msysgit.1.  I have a working directory in which I have cloned from many repositories.  However, now I want to transfer my changes only for a single repo.
How do I create a bundle for only one folder in my working tree using git bundle create command? Does anyone has clue on this?

Comment: How can you "clone from many repos" all into a single directory? Can you give us some details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git bundle` operates on branches, not on commits or directories (and `git` does not store directories - only files). If you added each directory via series of commits create a patch for them via `git format-patch` (http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-format-patch).

Comment: I have a working directory in windows.  I have added multiple remotes using "git remote add".  I am cloning from the remotes into the working directory, so I get all under the same folder (may be this is not a good practice to follow, but I have done it).  I have made changes to the code and committed.  However, I want to give the changes done to one module via email.  I have not created any local branches/tags.  All that I want to know how to transfer my changes to someone for review (I have no push access).  Please let me know if there is a way to create a package for the changes done.

Comment: ``git format-patch`` is what you need. http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-format-patch

Comment: create branches for the desired start and end commits, then create the bundle